# [Project1].[OT_ID] AS [OT_ID]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server database that is using 100% of my cpu. I have run the following script

```
    Select
    r.session_id,
    s.text,
    r.[status],
    r.blocking_session_id,
    r.cpu_time,
    r.total_elapsed_time
    from sys.dm_exec_requests r
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s
```

and got this as a result:

[image]

I did a search on the internet for anything relating to [Project1].[ot_id] AS [ot_id] but have not found anything that matches aside from SQL Server Bug site that suggests there is an issue with the code and that the bug was fixed back in 2013 but my biggest problem is that I do not know what code is causing this issue and there is no DBA currently employed by the company. I am a 2nd line engineer trying to understand SQL so please if you can help try to keep to laymans terms

Comment: What is your question?  The code seems to be doing what your query suggests.  Perhaps you should ask *another* question and explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to understand what Project1 is and why it is using up all my CPU rendering my server almost inoperable, I know from what i have read that the status:suspended means it is waiting for resources but is there a way i can find out what Project1 actually is?

Comment: `Project1` is a table - and it's not using your CPU. The _query_ that retrieves data from that table uses your CPU. The only way to debug this is to analyze the query, not by looking at some screen shots.

Comment: Ok, so where would that Project1 table reside, I use Sql Management studio and expand my database, expand tables and get a list of dbo.<tablename> but none of them have the name Project1 and my System Tables and FileTables are both empty containers?

Comment: Project1 is probably not the name of a table but an alias for a table. Further to the right in 'text' column in your screenshot the SQL command should contain "... FROM xyz as Project1 WHERE..." where 'xyz' is the real name of the table.

Comment: See this question as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131527/why-is-the-entity-framework-generating-this-sql, it seems to be the same framework in use since it says 'linq' at the beggining of each row in your screenshot

Comment: Hello Joakim, Thank you, I will have a read through

Answer (score 0):

I have followed Joakim's first instruction and found my table, its an application Audit table that seems to be erroring so I have disabled it and my CPU usage has dropped from 100% to 4%